# How to active a virtualenv with pyenv installed

Tags: python, pyenv, python-venv

I use `pyenv` for handling my python versions. I also use `virtualenv` for creating my virtual environments. In a new project, I made a new virtual environment with `python -m venv venv` to make a directory called `venv` that has a fresh python 3.6. I then did `source venv/bin/activate` expecting that to make `venv/bin/python` to be my default `python` from this directory, but when I do `command -v python`, I am told that `/Users/TheStrangeQuark/.pyenv/shims/python` is still the path. I also checked with `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"` and was printed with `/Users/jhuneau/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/bin/python`.

Why is `source venv/bin/activate` not working to set the python executable in this directory to use the virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

instead of

```
source venv/bin/active
```

Comment: That was a type, I did use activate